# How to tunnel Java GUI and other traffic through a VPN/PuTTY? (SSH encryption)

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, java, putty

I want to use a Java GUI application (Minecraft) through a VPN, since my parents firewall has blocked it, and I cannot login to the game launcher, because the application cannot connect to the authentication servers, since it is blocked by the firewall. Is there any way to tunnel all JavaGUI (if possible,all) applications through a VPN/PuTTY?

Comment: You should speak to your parents instead of trying to bypass blocks they have (presumably for a good reason) configured on their router.

Comment: ...I get a lot of these answers.

Comment: Please do not tell me this. It is not helpful.

Comment: Yes, you install a VPN client. There are many on the internet, which have you tried?

Comment: Psiphon VPN, CyberGhost,PuTTY,KiTTY(a fork of PuTTY). None of them work as for around 3 days ago. I would like to hear of any VPN that routes Minecraft traffic as well as browser traffic, or a way to get PuTTY to force Minecraft traffic through its tunnel, since it was not working as for 3 days ago.

Comment: EDIT:I would like the VPNs to have a Linux version, since my parents have put PCMonitor on my Windows installation, and I _would like_ my VPN client to have a Linux version since using a different OS to Windows would bypass PCMonitor, and the most readily OS i have access to is  Linux, since it is free and easy to use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

...Bump!
I have found the solution. I used a VPN service i found on the internet named NewIPVPN and i connected...I was able to login! By the way, still thanks to who contributed.